# Why I can't change the series format?

Tags: pandas

I have the following series I obtained from a read_html:

```
series:
1        417.951
2        621.710
3        164.042
4        189.963
5        555.123
6        213.494
7      2.873.093
```

I would like to remove the `.`  in order to apply some function to the numbers in that column.

So the desired output would be:

```
series:
1        417951
2        621710
3        164042
4        189963
5        555123
6        213494
7       2873093
```

I have tried a replace recieving the same result:

```
df.replace('.','')
```

and turn the series to a dataframe to see if that was the problem but it keeps returning initial series.

Comment: You need to assign back `df = df.replace('.', '')` or pass param `inplace=True` what is the final desired dtype here? string or numeric?

Comment: I don't really mind for the type (either series or df) given that I will append it to a dataframe

Comment: If you want numeric then you can do `df.replace(','m'').astype(int)` most pandas ops return a copy, nearly all methods include the arg `inplace`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need assign output to `Series` and if necessary convert to `int`, but also is necessary escape `.` by `\` and add parameter `regex` in [`Series.replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.replace.html):

```
series = series.replace('\.','', regex=True)
print (series)
1     417951
2     621710
3     164042
4     189963
5     555123
6     213494
7    2873093
Name: a, dtype: object
```

---

```
series = series.replace('\.','', regex=True).astype(int)
print (series)
1     417951
2     621710
3     164042
4     189963
5     555123
6     213494
7    2873093
Name: a, dtype: int32
```

Another solution is use [`str.replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.replace.html):

```
series = series.str.replace('.','')
print (series)
1     417951
2     621710
3     164042
4     189963
5     555123
6     213494
7    2873093
Name: a, dtype: object
```

But beter is use `thousands` parameter in [`read_html`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_html.html):

```
df = pd.read_html(url, thousands='.')
```